# Replacing value by another value

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, algebra

My question is that in Mathematica notebook when I write replacing commands, it didn't replace.

```
In[1]:= 2*x+y+1/.(x+y)->0
Out[1]:=1+2x+y
```

or

```
In[2]:= x+x+y+1/.(x+y)->0
Out[2]:=1+2x+y
```

Comment: For the second this works `HoldForm[x + x + y + 1] /. (x + y) -> 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReplaceAll` is not designed to do algebra, which does not try any algebraic transform. But `Reduce` etc. can do them.

However, I still can make something work with `ReplaceAll`.

For the first line, it's not replaced because there isn't any `x+y` at all, as you can see that with `FullForm`:

```
Plus[1,Times[2,x],y]
```

I recommend this command:

```
/. y->-x
```

For the second line, there is a `x+y` in `x+x+y+1`. But it's evaluated and then turns to `2x+y+1`.
You can use `Hold` to forbid it to be evaluated, and then use `ReleaseHold` after replacing:

```
ReleaseHold[Hold[x + x + y + 1] /. (x + y) -> 0]
```

For more convinience, use `Unevaluated` to hold it just once:

```
Unevaluated[x + x + y + 1] /. (x + y) -> 0
```

---

To break 2x to x+x, try:

```
Apply[Unevaluated@*Plus, Table[#2, #1] & @@ (2 x)]
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, Is there any command to break 2*x= x+x?

Comment: @HabibUllah No. You can imagine that: even if there is a function converting a scalar product to a sum, the result will finally be evaluated to be a product. So such a function is useless. But you can use non-standard evaluation as: `Table[#2,#1]&@@(2x)`, and replace its head `List` by `Plus` when needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could like this:

```
z /. ToRules[Reduce[z == 2 x + y + 1 && x + y == 0, {z, y}]]
```

which yields:

> 1 + x

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @HabibUllah Welcome to MSE. There are many ways to achieve your goal.. You can choose the way that best suits your purposes. Good luck:)